# extensionProperty not showing up in profile card

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I created an extension property in azure ad and now trying to display that information in profile card

Created extension property like this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0

and trying to display that attribute in profile card
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/add-properties-profilecard
but it doesnt show up

Answer (score 0):

You have created extension property but the profile card supports displaying only extension attribute which is not the same thing as extension property.

[Extension attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onpremisesextensionattributes?view=graph-rest-beta)

[Extension property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0)